# Nancy: is there a Server.MapPath("~/") equivalent?

Tags: c#, path, hosting, nancy

I can't seem to find an equivalent in Nancy for  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath() in the Nancy framework.

I just want to load a textfile relative to the application service.

I see this in the assembly

```
using Nancy;
using System;

namespace Nancy.Hosting.Self
{
    public class FileSystemRootPathProvider : IRootPathProvider, IHideObjectMembers
    {
        public FileSystemRootPathProvider();

        public string GetRootPath();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to use.

update: I just figured out anything I need to load can just be read/written from the bin/relase/ directory. Is that the assumed way to do it in a Nancy Self Hosting environment? I guess that would make sense.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can take a dependency on `IRootPathProvider` and use that to call `GetRootPath()` that will give you the root of your application and you can add from there (I would recommend using `Path.Combine`)

Comment: I ALWAYS use path.combine. it only took one production quality project to make me never combine path strings manually ever again =)

Comment: should IHideObjectMembers be implemented?

Comment: Thought that was just for intellisense/visual studio, so it's up to you. That just hides the base functions for code completion.

Comment: If it's in a `NancyModule` then just add `IRootPathProvider` to your constructor and you can start using it to call `GetRootPath()`

Comment: @TheCodeJunkie How can we access IRootPathProvider from the Bootstrapper ?

Comment: @reddy in `ApplicationStartup`: `var rootPathProvider = container.Resolve<IRootPathProvider>();`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need this in a static class (such as an `HtmlHelpers` extension) where the `IRootPathProvider` dependency can't be injected, at least AFAIK, you can use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` which is what `DefaultRootPathProvider` uses under the hood for .Net 4.x: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/DefaultRootPathProvider.cs